# How to use sessionScope in javascript?

Tags: javascript, session

I have a session object of User type called userdet, and it has one property called firstName.
I am trying to retrieve the firstName with the following code inside the script tag but I am unable to do it. I am doing everything in a xhtml page, so I have ruled out the scriplet tag.

```
var userName = "#{sessionScope['userdet']['firstName']}";
```

Comment: javascript doesn't have sessions, what is the server side language?

Comment: I am using Java Server Faces

Comment: The statement that you have a "session object" is not correct. In terms of JavaScript you only have a string. You have to convert it into [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals). A good way to start is [json.org](http://json.org).